# Objective-c OpenGLES knowing the screen coordinates of the objects/models

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, coordinates

Is there a way to get the screen coordinates of the objects in the 3d world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement [`gluProject()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluProject.xml).

EDIT: Mesa/SGI has [some code](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/tree/src/glu/sgi/libutil/project.c#n234).

EDIT2: Or grab a copy of [GLU for iOS](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-glu/).

Comment: @marcg11: Edited.  This is pretty much the easiest way.

Comment: Hey, do you know how to add the library into your project? The readme says: To compile for the simulator:

make ARCH=i386 PLATFORM=iPhoneSimulator

To compile for a device:

make ARCH=armv6 PLATFORM=iPhoneOS

Answer (score 1):

Just implement the transformations of the OpenGL pipeline: modelview, projection, perspective devide, viewport. You get query the current matrices with glGetDoublev and the viewort with glGetIntegerv.

Then you have to compute projection matrix times modelview matrix = MVP.

now for each vertex v compute MVP*v.

then compute v /= v.w;

So you got coordinates in range [-1,1]x[-1,1], the last thing is scaling and translating this into [x,x+w]x[y,y+h] (which are the values of the viewport).

You can also take a look info pages of the OpenGL reference for glFrustum, glViewport, to see how all these transformations are done.

Comment: Wow lol, I don't know that much openGLES. So the funcion gluproject is not implmeneted? Thanks btw.

Comment: I don't know, I have only desktop GL experience, where gluProject is implemented. If it's there, you can use it (it actually does exactly what i wrote). But perhaps genpfault's link to gluProject provides you a better explanation of its workings than my answer. With those explanations it should be quite easy to implement yourself.

Comment: I'll have it a look. I don't know how much desktop opengl is different than openglES for iphone.

Comment: It shouldn't be different in this respect. I only meant, that I don't know if there is a GLU in GL ES

Comment: I think that there isn't glu un GLES :(